How to decrypt TLS traffic from a windows process?
I'm trying to decrypt TLS traffic from a windows application. Does anyone know what the possible methods are to do this?

The whole point of TLS is to keep encrypted data secure. Unless you have access to the TLS session data you'll get nowhere. If you're clever, and very determined, you might be able to launch a MITM attack, but that's outside the scope of [so]
